# If parameters or arguments is null

Tags: javascript, class, parameter-passing

## JAVASCRIPT

Hello pro's, my only idea of if some of my arguments/parameters in my class are null, is only the 'if statement'. Is there any efficient way or method instead of  if statement.

Because It displays 'undefined' If I didnt put a 'if statement' there. I only want is the 'undefined' word wont display if some of my paremeter/arguments are null/undefined

```
class People {
constructor ({fname, mname, 
lname, favs}) {
this.fn = fname;
this.mn = mname;
this.ln = lname;
this.favs = [favs]
this.init();
}
```

// Here, I use if statement only.

```
init(){

if (this.favs === null){
```

console.log(`${this.­fn} ${this.mn} 
    ${this.ln}`)
    }
    else {
    console.log(`${this.­fn} 
    ${this.mn} ${this.ln} 
    ${this.favs} ${this.num} 
    ${this.color} ${this.hobby}` )
    }

```
}
}

const $test = new People (
{
fname: 'Some',
mname: 'Random', 
lname: 'String',
favs: []
}
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using default parameters? This way you're sure that optional parameters get initialized with default values (then, you never get undefined). Something like this.

```js
class Person {
   constructor (fname, lname, favs) {
      this.fname = fname;
      this.lname = lname;
      this.favs = favs || [];   

      this.init();
   }

   init () {
      console.log(`Hi, I'm ${this.fname} ${this.lname}. My hobbies are: ${this.favs.join(',')}`);
   }
}

const joe = new Person('Joe', 'Doe');
```

Comment: So she will ignore the favs If I didnt put a value there sir?

Comment: It just assign a default value in case none is provided, this way `favs` will never be undefined.

Comment: I see now. Thank you for helping sir!

Comment: Happy to be helpful. Rembember to mark the question as answered.

Comment: One more thing, if removed the OR ( || ) in favs, it displays undefined. My concern is, why is that, whats does OR for sir?

Comment: That statement simply checks if the supplied favs is undefined or not, if it isn't then it uses the provieded value, else it uses the default empty array.